# Div container doesn't fit content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Div container doesn't fit content
I made a version of my page with the principal components to share with you and try to resolve this problem. Well, the problem is that when you expand horizontally the page the images are cutted in the bottom. I want leave the page like that, therefore without visual changes.
PS: I'm using bootstrap

```
.image-container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;    
  position:absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/power96/q15oo62d/

Comment: Is there really a need to position the image container absolutely? Also, your jQuery code needs to be modularized.

Comment: Yeah you should remove the position:absolute; That doesnt make sense

Comment: If I remove position:absolute the animation doesn't work the same as before. Just try it...

Answer (score 0):

I added an inherit to the images

```
.image-container img{
   height:inherit;
   width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q15oo62d/12/

Comment: you know bootstrap has a really good slider. You should look into that. It will save you a bit of time http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel